# React native clickable substring inside TextInput

Tags: react-native

I want a `TextInput` to be generated where some part of the text is clickable. In particular for iOS.

Conceptually something like the following:

```
<TextInput>
  <Text>
    I want to be able to click 
  </Text>
  <Text onPress={() => console.log("test")}>
    here
  </Text>
</TextInput>
```

Where the `console.log` is triggered only when pressing 'here'.

- I am aware of workarounds where we subscribe to the `onFocus` and the `onSelectionChange` event. This however will not suite the more general problem I am working on.
- I have tried using `TouchableOpacity` around a `Text` tag, however that will not even render the text 'here'. That is, when the `TouchableOpacity` is *inside* the `TextInput`.

Comment: TouchableOpacity can be used around a Text tag, your error is somewhere else (https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchableopacity)

Comment: @TheoMartinez But the TouchableOpactiy should be inside the TextInput, is that also possible? For that is when the text isn't rendered. Outside a TextInput a TouchableOpacity can indeed wrap a Text tag.

Comment: Did you try in a View with flexDirection row and negative margin ?

Comment: @TheoMartinez: not sure where you'd like me to place the View. However I just did the following: Within the TextInput I 1) wrapped the Text tags with a View, which renders nothing, and 2) wrapped only the second Text tag with a View, which does the same as wrapping inside a TouchableOpacity: 'here' is not rendered. 
I used the flexDirection and negative margin as you suggested.

Comment: It seems like anything besides the Text tag will not render properly inside the TextInput tag.

Comment: More like a View wrapping the <TextInput> and the <TouchableOpacity> at the same level

Comment: @TheoMartinez The clickable part needs to be inside the TextInput for the broader use case. That's why I am looking for such generic solution.